# What is the license of models built on pretrained embeddings?

Tags: license

I was trying to figure out this problem in the internet. What if I train embeddings on the wikipedia texts? And then use them in training of my model?

For example, fastText embeddings are distributed like Wikipedia under https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/. This states:

```
 ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, 
 or build upon the material, you must distribute your  
 contributions under the same license as the original.
```

Does it mean that my model should be also distributed on the same license?

Comment: This is actually a difficult legal question. You should ask it to a lawyer.